# How to get first record group by non relational join query, Django?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

**Model:**

```
class AD(model.Model):
    serial              = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    po_number           = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class IDA(model.Model):
    serial              = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)

class POR(models.Model):
    po_number               = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    is_closed_po            = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**Raw Query:**

```
Select MIN(a.serial) as first_value, a.po_number
From AD a
Join IDA i ON a.serial=i.serial
Join POR p ON a.po_number=p.po_number
Where p.is_closed_po=0
Group By a.po_number
```

**What I'm trying to do in Django:**

```
AD.objects.extra(
    select={'is_closed_po': 'por.is_closed_po'},
    tables=['por', 'ida'],
    where=['ad.po_number = por.po_number',
           'ad.serial = ida.serial',
           'is_closed_po = 0'
           ],
).values('serial', 'po_number')
```

How can I achieve this in Django? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Both joins are actually [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#filtering-on-a-subquery-or-exists-expressions) predicates. After filtering AD you will need to [group by po_number](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values) with `annotate(Min(serial))`. Please take a look at examples in the docs.